# How to simulate an order from top to bottom in Magento?

Tags: magento

It's my first project and it's not hard to make per se *just a theme and basic customizations) but I haven't found a way to test a complete transaction, from when you place the item in your cart until it's ready for shipment and a suposedly delivered object.

How could I know, when the site will launch that everything will be in order?

Comment: The easiest way I can think of is "writing" (recording) a selenium script. I don't know any way to do that :(

Comment: and I have no clue what that is :-s thanks for the answer though :D

Comment: http://seleniumhq.org/ Selenium is a Framework/Browser extension to run automated tests on a browser. The alternative is mink/behat, for example with the tools you find here https://github.com/MageTest